# How to perform Rename Symbol (F2) action on Template Literal Types - VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way VSCode can perform a *Rename Symbol (F2)* action on [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) (Typescript).

For example: `type apiStateType = "idel" | "pending" | "done";`

If I do F2 on `idel` it'd rename in the current file but not in others which are using `apiStateType` `idel`. Currently, I need to compile `tsc` to see if this change has any consequences and do it in all other files. Other option is to perform a global search and replace but that could have side-effects.